# After call back from payment gateway Laravel 5.6 page expired due to inactivity

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am integrating payment gateway in Laravel 5.6 but
The problem is sometimes call back URL from gateway page expire due to inactivity and sometimes its work perfectly.

while I have added call back URL in App\Http\Middleware; to prevent checking CSRF token.

Please help me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @UdhavSarvaiya  actually this is happening when redirecting from payment gateway site.
Not always but sometime.
while i added call back URL in App\Http\Middleware. If cache issue then why sometime working?
In my browser working fine always but in some of my client geting page expire due to inactivity error.

Comment: Make sure to read the payment gateway documentation and following their payment flow. Surely, each payment must be done through a new session rather than using an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

into the `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
replace 
    protected $except = [
      'add payment url'
  ];
from protected $except= [];
```